# Stock status and back orders in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, inventory, out-of-stock, stock-status, backorder

I want to enable customers to be able to place backorders

In the [docs](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/inventory.html) its states for stock status of "Out of Stock" the following

> Unless Backorders are activated, prevents the product from being
>   available for purchase and removes the listing from the catalog."

This then implies I should set my products to be "Out of Stock" but enable backorders so I have the following settings as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

The issue is that on the frontend the customer still is not able to purchase the product. See screenshot below:

[image]

I have tried to reindex and flushed all the caches but still no luck. Could any one advise?

Answer (score 0):

Please enable backorder from configuration also:

```
Stores – Configuration – Catalog – Inventory – Product Stock Options tab:
```

[image]

Comment: The issue still exists unfortunately and as I have unticked "Use config settings" making any changes here won't have any effect surely?

Comment: so you have selected Allow Qty Below 0 also after untick Config setting?

Comment: Correct yes but no luck

Comment: Please have a look on this, might be it is related to your issue https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10304

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is that stock status is out of stock, it should be ''in stock'' with qty 0 to allow back-orders.

More info here: https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/inventory-backorders.html